# Creating Datetime index in python

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, time-series, datetimeindex

I am trying to create datetime index in python. I have an existing dataframe with date column (`CrimeDate`), here is a snapshot of it:

[image]

The date is not in datetime format though.

I intent to have an output similar to the below format, but with my existing dataframe's date column-

[image]

The `Crimedate` column has approx. 334192 rows and start date from 2021-04-24 to 1963-10-30 (all are in sequence of months and year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to convert the date column to datetime:

```
df['CrimeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CrimeDate'])
```

And after that set that column as the index:

```
df.set_index(['CrimeDate'], inplace=True)
```

Once set, you can access the datetime index directly:

```
df.index
```